# Swagger client, adding a fixed parameter to the request

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I am looking for a way to add a fixed parameter to every request the client sends to the server.

For example: `param1=false`. The default value for the server is `param1=true`, but I want the generated client to send `false` with every request. Is this somehow possible?

I have tried:

- `default: false` - which is documented to not work for this case
- `defaultValue: false` - which seems to only work for the UI
- `enum: -false` - which also seems to only work for the UI

**Edit**

When I generate Java Code with

```
    - name: param1
      in: query
      type: boolean
      required: true
      enum: [true]
```

The generated code looks like this:

```
private com.squareup.okhttp.Call routeGetCall(Boolean param1){
        Object localVarPostBody = null;

        // verify the required parameter 'param1' is set
        if (param1 == null) {
            throw new ApiException("Missing the required parameter 'param1' when calling routeGet(Async)");
        }
        ... more code ...
```

Param1 is never forced to be true. I can even set it false. Therefore, enum seems to be only working for the UI?

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible to have a constant parameter with just one possible value, such as `?param1=true`:

```
      parameters:
        - name: param1
          in: query
          type: boolean
          required: true
          enum: [true]
```

if a parameter has multiple possible values, such as `true` / `false` (as in your example), the spec cannot force any specific value for the parameter. **It's up to the client** to decide which value to use.

That is, the generated client code needs to be modified to use a specific parameter value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your supplied sample does not work for me since the enum does not seem to have an effect on the generated code, see my updated question.